# What is the dimension of the set generated by $z \mapsto z + 1$ and $z \mapsto \frac{z}{1+z}$?

Tags: general-topology, fractions, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let's say I have subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ generated by two elements, I wanted to compute the limit set.  So I wrote down two matrices:

$$
A =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) ,\;
B =  \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right)
$$
These can be written as two maps of fractional linear transformations or [Möbius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) transformations:
$$  z \mapsto z + 1\;\text{ and }z\mapsto  \frac{z}{1+z}$$
The plots of the orbits of these sets was surprising.  I represented a fraction $\frac{a}{b} = [a:b] \in \mathbb{R}P^2$ as a line in the [Euclidean plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_space).

> What are the basic properties of this fractal?  E.g. it's [dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension) or that it's not [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space).

[image]

a closer look:

[image]

an even closer look:

[image]

Comment: As it stands, wouldn't your $B$ be represented as $f(z)=\frac{z}{z+1}$ instead of $f(z)=\frac{-1}{z+1}$?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the set you've found is actually *all* of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, not just a subgroup, because the two matrices $A$ and $B$ generate the group; the points you've plotted will eventually include all of the points on the circle that are on lines of rational slope.

The reason why you find a fractal-like structure is because of an interesting semi-universal property where simple solutions of an equation, simple points in a structure, etc. 'repel' other points.  In this case, it manifests as gaps around all of the points that are on rational lines $ax+by=0$ with particularly small values of $a$ and $b$; thought of another way, there are wider 'gaps' around rational numbers $\frac ab$ (in a Farey sequence) with small $a$ and $b$ than there are around more complicated numbers.

To see an example of this in action, look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#/media/File:Farey_diagram_horizontal_arc_9.svg which demonstrates all the points in the Farey sequence of order 9 (that is, all rational numbers $\frac ab$ with $0\leq\frac ab\leq 1$ and $b\leq 9$).  Note that the nearest fraction to $0$ is $\frac19$, at distance $\frac19$, and a nearest fraction to $\frac12$ is $\frac49$, at distance $\frac1{18}$; by contrast, the nearest fraction to $\frac45$, for instance, is $\frac79$, which is only distance $\frac1{45}$ away from it!

The distribution of the Farey sequence is, arguably, understood both well and poorly at the same time.  It's known that the order-$N$ Farey sequence $F_N$ has $\theta(N^2)$ points in it (in fact, approximately $\frac6{\pi^2} N^2$, where the $\frac6{\pi^2}$ comes from $\frac1{\zeta(2)}$) and that it approaches a uniform distribution as $N\to\infty$; it's also known that the gaps between adjacent numbers range from $\theta(\frac1N)$ to $\theta(\frac1{N^2})$ in size. (For instance, the gap next to $\frac12$ is always approximately $\frac1{2N}$.)  But the question of how quickly it approaches a uniform distribution is much trickier:

Suppose that $f_n$ is the $n$th fraction in the order-$N$ sequence $F_N$, and consider the distance between $f_n$ and the point $\frac n{|F_N|}$ that corresponds to a uniform distribution with as many points as the Farey sequence.  Now, we can look at the 'mean square' size of these distances over all the sequence, $\displaystyle \Delta_N=\sum_{n=1}^{|F_N|}(f_n-\frac n{|F_N|})^2$; this is a measure of the total discrepancy of the sequence. It's known that $\Delta_N\in o(1)$ as $N\to\infty$; this is one way of formalizing the idea that the Farey sequence approaches a uniform distribution. But how does $\Delta_N$ go to zero as $N\to\infty$?  Well, the statement that $\Delta_N\in O(N^{-r})$ for all $r\lt 1$ would be nice; this says that $\Delta_N$ is 'essentially $1/N$', which is as good as we could hope for.  But this statement is equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis!  (See [the Wikipedia page on Farey fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence#Riemann_hypothesis) and [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204678/farey-fractions-estimate-equivalent-to-the-prime-number-theorem) for more on this)

Comment: i guess you're right. i guess i can examine other choices of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: the matrices $\left(  \begin{array}{cc}  1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array}\right)$ and $\left(  \begin{array}{cc}  1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array}\right)$ correspond to $z \mapsto z + 1$ and $z \mapsto \frac{z}{z+1}$.  These might not generate all $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ or all continued fractions.

Comment: @cactus314 That doesn't work; letting $C=\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{array} \right)$, we have $C^2B^{-1}=A$, so your new matrices generate all of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ again.  You might look at the subgroup generated by $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ and $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{array} \right)$; this subgroup is free (by the Ping-pong lemma) and is a proper subgroup.

Comment: we're observing the rate of convergence and it's rather slow and uneven. and maybe that's related to the spectrum of Laplacian on $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\backslash \mathbb{H}$. if i put a $2$ instead of the $1$ the thing looks like a circular Cantor set and I can't draw a picture yet.

Comment: Are you iterating forwards and back, or just forwards? (I.e. are you using positive and negative powers of your generators, or just positive?) In any case, I would absolutely expect a Cantor structure for that limit set at least in "forward" iteration.

Comment: I have seen it as both the [semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semigroup) and as the [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)).  The ideas was to explore the Hausdorff dimension of limit sets of the subgroups, as in this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.5021).

Answer (score -1):

It's a one dimensional object that is connected and path connected.  It is one dimensional because you can totally describe it using one variable

$$f(\theta) = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$$

Also, it is definitely connected but the image that you are seeing looks disconnected just because a computer has limits in presenting data.